# Limitar campo sql server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla con el campo contraseña que tiene ser ser limitado a 6 ni mas ni menos , probé con el modificador check pero solo se asignarle o números o letras, hay alguna manera de limitarlo a 6 pero que puedan ser cualquiera de las 2 cosas?

```
create table Empleado
(ci int not null,
contraseña varchar(6) not null,
nombreCompleto varchar(20) not null,
primary key(ci),
logica bit default(0))
go
```

Comment: Y si la contraseña solo tiene un carácter? quieres que se rellenen el resto con números y letras aleatorias? Antes o despues? Y si tiene mas de 6 caracteres ser recorta del inicio o del fin? mmm esta muy abierta la pregunta

Comment: Pues en SQL estándar es con un CONSTRAINT.

Comment: Esa validación hazla en la capa de presentación, no en la base de datos.

Comment: si,me parece mas practico ponerla en presentacion, pero como enseñaron a usar modificadores check y otras cosas, tengo que hacer muchos controles a nivel de base de datos .

Answer (score 2):

Ok, obviando el hecho que tener una contraseña con un largo fijo exacto es mala práctica, que sean sólo 6 caracteres lo hace aún peor y que además quede guardado en texto plano...esto se puede hacer fácilmente:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado ( ci int NOT NULL, 
                        contraseña varchar(6) NOT NULL CHECK(LEN(contraseña) = 6), 
                        nombreCompleto varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
                        PRIMARY KEY(ci), 
                        logica bit DEFAULT(0) 
                      )
;
```

Comment: se que es una mala practica pero la idea del proyecto es aplicar modificadores y otras cosas mas, pero en este caso es a nivel de base de datos y cuando entregue anteriormente , solo con contraseña varchar (6) , me dijieron que no era suficiente control.